# ¿ De que manera puedo hacer que las notificaciones me funcionen en flutter?

Tags: flutter

Estamos desarrollando una app de agendamiento, tenemos que lograr que llegue notificacion al usuario cuando se acerca la hora de la cita, hemos intentado programar la notificación con flutter_local_notifications inicialmente con un boton para mirar si responder y llega la notificación, pero no llega la notificación, y tampoco sale error en la plataforma:

Adjunto el código:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class NotificationScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Pantalla de notificación'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Mostrar notificación'),
          onPressed: () {
            showNotification();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> initNotifications() async {
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');



    const InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,

    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

  Future<void> showNotification() async {
    const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
    AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'your channel id',
      'your channel name',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );

    const NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidNotificationDetails,
    );

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      1,
      'Titulo de notificación',
      'Esta es una notificación de prueba para mostrar en el canal. Los quiero mucho.',
      notificationDetails,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Según el propio package de Flutter local notifications, las notificaciones programadas (es decir, las que se deben ejecutar por sí solas en X tiempo) puede dar problemas con algunos dispositivos. Deberías revisar la doc, puede que sea eso. De todos modos, creo que para este tipo de casos, es necesario un backend personalizado que se encargue de enviar las peticiones push a los clientes.

Comment: Te aconsejo que uses firebase_messaging en conjunto con flutter_local_notifications, así podras generar notificaciones inclusive usando postman para realizar las pruebas, así me manejo yo actualmente